# Why was my question on a php.net-comment downvoted?

Tags: support

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228708/why-is-this-php-net-comment-downvoted?noredirect=1#comment56201394_34228708). As you can see, noone really liked it, and people voted to close it as off-topic.

I don't have a problem with this, I only want to understand why.

In my question, I ask for the explanation of a comment on php.net.

The first comment to my question is that the comment referred to is "wrong", and well, I could imagine that the people who downvoted that very comment felt the same. Anyway, as I have lined out in the question, I have a different opinion. So I ask for an explanation on why the comment on php.net was downvoted. From an answer I would have expected to correct my opinion, but instead, my question was downvoted too.

Comment: Not so sure why it wasn't closed as "Primarily opinion based", the reasons chosen strongly suggest an "ugh, let's get rid of this" preference.  In general, criticizing language design at a site where most visitors are rabid language fans is a recipe for DVs.  Equally true for php.net as the SO [php] tag.  Also note how unconstructive this is, they of course can't change this anymore without breaking lots and lots of code.  And who knows, maybe the php.net comment got so many DVs because the user name is grossly lewd or the post has too many spelling errors.  Opinions, not facts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In my question, I ask for the explanation of a comment on php.net.

That's the problem; you're not asking about a programming problem, you're asking about a social problem on *another* site.  It's already off-topic.

Regardless of that comment's correctness, it's still downvoted, and I doubt that the average layman around here would have even considered to care that it was on PHP.net.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll accept this.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer - You're a champ for coming to meta to ask and then reasonably accepting this answer. Awesome! However some of us feel you've been misunderstood (largely by how you've worded your question), i.e. you didn't _mean_ to ask about a social problem on another site; you _meant_ to ask what the flaw in your understanding was that leads to such a contradictorily downvoted comment. (At least, I _hope_ that's what you meant, or I'd fully agree with Makoto.) I've edited your question with others' help and it has now been reopened.

Comment: @AndrewCheong thanks i commented on the original question